# <select> tags are not staying within specified borders in Firefox

Tags: html, css, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am creating an app the requires me to use 3 `<select>` tags that are stacked on top of each other. I need said tags to be flush with each other and also not leap over the background div's boundaries. I am making this work out fine in *Google Chrome*, but when I check it out *Firefox*, everything goes haywire. The select tags are nearly over the boundaries of the background div in unacceptable ways.

***A visual example of my problem (Firefox on left Google Chrome on right)...***
[image]

***Here is my HTML...***

```
<div id='wr-main-wrap'>
    <div id='wr-wrapper'>
        <div id='wr-opaq-background'></div>
        <div id='input-wrapper'>
            <div>
                <h3 class='label-text'>work day length:</h3>
                <select ng-model='ratioControl.workday'>
                    <option value='1'>1 Hour</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3 class='label-text'>break frequency:</h3>
                <select ng-model='ratioControl.breakspan'>
                    <option value='.5'>30 Minutes</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3 class='label-text'>break lengths:</h3>
                <select ng-model='ratioControl.breaklength'>
                    <option value='5'>5 Minutes</option>
                </select>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Here is my CSS...***

```
#wr-main-wrap{
    width: 19em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#wr-wrapper{
    width: 17em;
    margin: 3.5em auto;
}

#wr-opaq-background{
    position: absolute;
    width: 17em;
    height: 7em;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: .7;
    border-radius: .25em;
}

#input-wrapper{
    margin: 5em 0;
    padding: .85em 0 0 .6em;
}

.label-text{
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
    margin-bottom: .8em;
    word-spacing: .1em;
    display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;
    width: 9em;
}

select{
    width: 6em;
    margin: 0 0 1.1em 0;
    background-color: white;
    border: black solid .1em;
}
```

I have check on stack overflow and the internets quite a bit, and have not found anything to answer my question. It is worth nothing that I am using *Angular* in case that may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following CSS:

```
#wr-wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I thought it had to do with the positioning. But now that I see the picture, the issue seems to be with the width. Try a different unit like `90px` or `45%` or `0.4vw`.

Comment: When I do that, it still is different on both browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The `<input>` tags themselves needed a height and width, otherwise, they would just adjust to the browser's default settings. This is completely unpredictable. I used `%` as a unit of measurement.